# c3p0 do not timeout when are impossible to reach the host

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

The first thing my program do when open is try to connect in the database, if the c3p0 wont connect it freezes and do not raise any error message.

The weird thing is that with **MySql** I got `java.net.UnknownHostException`, but with **SqlServer** nothing, it keeps trying forever.

I want to catch the error and do something. I tryed set this properties but no luck.

```xml
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="60"/>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="60"/>
```

My persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.lala.Something</class>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <!-- connection -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=str"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="teste"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="teste"/>
            <!-- hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
            <!-- c3p0 -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the connection param `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

Comment: @EddieB I did and worked, probably because I remove the param `autoReconnect=true` also, hahaha, but with the SqlServer not yet, it just not raise the exception. I updated the URL of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved adding this two properties:

**acquireRetryAttempts**

Defines how many times c3p0 will try to acquire a new Connection from the database before giving up. If this value is less than or equal to zero, c3p0 will keep trying to fetch a Connection indefinitely.

**breakAfterAcquireFailure**

If true, a pooled DataSource will declare itself broken and be permanently closed if a Connection cannot be obtained from the database after making acquireRetryAttempts to acquire one. If false, failure to obtain a Connection will cause all Threads waiting for the pool to acquire a Connection to throw an Exception, but the DataSource will remain valid, and will attempt to acquire again following a call to getConnection().

```xml
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Though the accepted was helpful in reducing the number of attempted to "acquire" a connection from 30 (!) to 3 the getConnection() would still "hang" for ages if the server was not responsive. It appears that c3p0 uses the different nomenclature of "check out/in" for a connection to be added to the pool. Therefore setting checkoutTimeout to something other than 0 (wait for ever!) solves the problem.

I'm guessing acquireRetryAttempts and checkoutTimeout and applied to each of the intialPoolSize connections.

Answer (score 0):

If c3p0 attempts to acquire Connections from a database, and those acquisition attempts "hang" — they neither succeed nor fail with an Exception — that's bad. Hanging acquires will eventually saturate the Thread pool, forcing it to be declare an `APPARENT DEADLOCK` and reconstruct itself.

Neither of the two properties you've tried to set are relevant to this problem. If you want to work around these hangs, the c3p0 configuration property to look at would be [maxAdministrativeTaskTime](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxAdministrativeTaskTime).

Comment: I add the property `maxAdministrativeTaskTime=10` and aperentely it has interrupt the thread, but yet instead of stop the c3p0 try to connect again, and then interrupt, and then try again, and so on...

Ok, It is a little especific, I am trying to avoid a problem that happens only if I can not connect to the database, but I wonder if nobody had this kind problem